# Error through remote Spark Job: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, spark-structured-streaming, azure-hdinsight

#### Problem

I am trying to run a remote Spark Job through IntelliJ with a Spark HDInsight cluster (HDI 4.0). In my Spark application I am trying to read an input stream from a folder of parquet files from Azure blob storage using Spark's Structured Streaming built in `readStream` function.

The code works as expected when I run it on a Zeppelin notebook attached to the HDInsight cluster. However, when I deploy my Spark application to the cluster, I encounter the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem cannot access its superinterface org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.TokenAspect$TokenManagementDelegator`

Subsequently, I am unable to read any data from blob storage.

The little information I found online suggested that this is caused by a version conflict between Spark and Hadoop. The application is run with Spark `2.4` prebuilt for Hadoop `2.7`.

#### Fix

To fix this, I ssh into each head and worker node of the cluster and manually downgrade the Hadoop dependencies to `2.7.3` from `3.1.x` to match the version in my local `spark/jars` folder. After doing this , I am then able to deploy my application successfully. Downgrading the cluster from HDI 4.0 is not an option as it is the only cluster that can support Spark `2.4`.

#### Summary

To summarize, could the issue be that I am using a Spark download prebuilt for Hadoop `2.7`? Is there a better way to fix this conflict instead of manually downgrading the Hadoop versions on the cluster's nodes or changing the Spark version I am using?

Comment: Hi @Maria, Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After troubleshooting some previous methods I had attempted before, I've come across the following fix:

In my `pom.xml` I excluded the `hadoop-client` dependency automatically imported by the `spark-core` jar. This dependency was version `2.6.5` which conflicted with the cluster's version of Hadoop. Instead, I import the version I require.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version.major}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependency>
```

After making this change, I encountered the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0`. Further research revealed this was due to a problem with the Hadoop configuration on my local machine. Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41851066/) article's advice, I modified the `winutils.exe` version I had under `C://winutils/bin` to be the version I required and also added the corresponding `hadoop.dll`. After making these changes, I was able to successfully read data from blob storage as expected.

**TLDR**
Issue was the auto imported `hadoop-client` dependency which was fixed by excluding it & adding the new `winutils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` under `C://winutils/bin`.

This no longer required downgrading the Hadoop versions within the HDInsight cluster or changing my downloaded Spark version.

Comment: For me it was enough to add the following dependency (no need for `exclusions`): `<dependency><groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId><artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId><version>3.0.0</version></dependency>`

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**
I was facing same issue while running fat jar with hadoop 2.7 and spark 2.4 on cluster with hadoop 3.x ,
I was using maven shade plugin.

**Observation:**
While building fat jar it was including jar  *org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.6.5*  which has class class *org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem*.
Which was causing problem  in hadoop 3

**Solution:**
I have excluded this jar while building fat jar as below.Issue got resolved.

[image]

Comment: I met the same issue , and it works as per the solution here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue due to the fact that I missed the **% provided** declarations in the built.sbt file.

While I run the sbt clean assembly, it creates a jar file that matches my local environment versions.

**Previously**

```
libraryDependencies ++= {

  val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"    
  Seq(
    "com.typesafe"      %  "config"        % "1.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-core"   % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-sql"    % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-hive"    % sparkVersion
  )
}
```

**Now**

```
libraryDependencies ++= {

  val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"
  
  Seq(
    "com.typesafe"      %   "config"        % "1.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-core"    % sparkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-sql"     % sparkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-hive"    % sparkVersion % "provided"
  )
}
```

**provided** - This indicates that the specified dependency is expected to be provided by the Spark cluster or another environment at runtime. It means that you don't want to include this dependency in your project's JAR file because it's already available externally.